# date_diff outputs wrong value

Tags: php, datetime

```
$end=date_create("2013-07-30 00:30:33");
$now=date_create();
$x=date_diff($end,$now);
echo $x->format('%a days');
```

When I use %a it returns 45 days which is correct, when I use %d it returns 15 days. What is problem there?

Comment: abs(15 - 30) == 15? (%d compares the days? not the overall)

Comment: So I should work with %a. I can't find anywhere explanation of those %characters. Does %h for hours and %i for minutes work correctly?

Comment: try `$x->format('%m month, %d days');` you are only outputting the days when doing `%d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 15 are the days calculated from difference by the months.

For example: (from http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

```
<?php

$january = new DateTime('2010-01-01');
$february = new DateTime('2010-02-01');
$interval = $february->diff($january);

// %a will output the total number of days.
echo $interval->format('%a total days')."\n";

// While %d will only output the number of days not already covered by the
// month.
echo $interval->format('%m month, %d days');

?>
```

The above example will output:

31 total days

1 month, 0 days

Answer (score 1):

Note that `date_diff($end,$now);` returns [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) and it has its own format:

[FROM PHP DOC](http://www.php.net/dateinterval.format#refsect1-dateinterval.format-parameters)

> a = Total number of days as a result of a DateTime::diff() or (unknown) otherwise

And

> d = Days, numeric

You can not have `45 days` in a single month so its basically using `%d` or `%m month %d days`

```
45 days //or 
1 month 15 days
```